# не получается выполнить запрос к сайту в цикле(Retrofit)

Tags: android, retrofit, viewmodel, response, livedata

Я хочу загрузить 50 рандомных фотографий с сайта [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com), но апи позволяет выгрузить за один запрос к серверу максимум 30 фотографий. В моем классе ViewModelActivity

```
public class ViewModelActivity extends ViewModel {

    private NetworkEndpoints networkEndpoints = UnsplashClient
            .getUnsplashClient()
            .create(NetworkEndpoints.class);

    private MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> getMutableLiveData() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            photos.addAll(initData)
        }
        mutableLiveData.value(photos);
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    private List<Photo> initData() {
        List<Photo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        networkEndpoints.getRandomPhotos(10).enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
                list.addAll(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return list;
    }
```

}

я создал метод `initData`, возвращаемое значение которого я помещаю в ArrayList. ArrayList я помещаю в переменую `mutableLiveData` в цикле. Затем в классе `MainActivity` я получаю список фотографий.

Проблема заключается в том, что при выполнении метода `initData()` переопределенные методы `onResponce` и `onFailure` не выполняются и метод возвращает пустой список. Но при попытке выполнения следующего кода, в котором я значение responce.body() кладу на прямую в переменную LiveData запрос выполняется корректно.

```
public class ViewModelActivity extends ViewModel {

    private NetworkEndpoints networkEndpoints = UnsplashClient
            .getUnsplashClient()
            .create(NetworkEndpoints.class);

    private MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> getMutableLiveData() {
        mutableLiveData = initData();
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    private MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> initData() {
        networkEndpoints.getRandomPhotos(10).enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
                mutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

Но в этом случае я не знаю как выполнить запрос в цикле.

Comment: `enqueue` - асинхронная операция, в неё передаются колбеки, которые вызовутся, когда данные придут из сети (или при ошибке). Ван нужно почитать что такое асинхронность и асинхронное программирование

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon спасибо большое что указали мне направление, в котором необходимо искать. Благодаря этому я понял как выполняется метод enqueue и каким образом его использовать в моем классе ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Как мне подсказали в комментарии к моему вопросу enqueue - это асинхронная операция. Операции, описанные в методах `onResponce` и `onFailure` выполнятся только когда от сервера поступят данные. Для того что бы получить данные из responce.body() я написал следующий код.

```
public class PhotoViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private NetworkEndpoints networkEndpoints = UnsplashClient
            .getUnsplashClient()
            .create(NetworkEndpoints.class);

    private MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    List<Photo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> getMutableLiveData() {
        initData();
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    private void initData() {
        networkEndpoints.getRandomPhotos(10).enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    list.addAll(response.body());
                }
                if(list.size() < 50){
                    initData();
                }
                mutableLiveData.setValue(list);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

В методе `onResponse` рекурсивно вызываю мой метод `initData()` после записи данных в коллекцию. Как только рекурсия прерывается выполняется запись данных из коллекции в `mutableLiveData`, которая в свою очередь уведомляет своего слушателя о том что данные изменились. Таким образом благодаря рекурсии мне удалось выгрузить 50 фото с сервера при ограничении в 30 фото. Так же хочу посоветовать [это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i_9ZNNhn2I). В нем подробно рассматривается асинхронное программирование. Я уверен что мое решение не является идеальным и требует доработок, но оно работает.

Comment: Вы в данном коде делаете **последовательно** 5 запросов (каждый следующий запрос начинается только когда закончится предыдущий), но ведь enqueue асинхронная, можно сразу создать в цикле 5 запросов и они выполнятся **параллельно**, т.е. в 5 раз быстрей

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon вы имеете в виду, что мне нужно вызвать метод initData в цикле?

Comment: Либо `initData` вызвать в цикле, либо в `initData` вызывать `networkEndpoints.getRandomPhotos(10).enqueue` в цикле. Естественно при этом тогда нужно убрать рекурсивный вызов из `onResponse`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon да, спасибо за вашу правку, этот вариант работает)